# Upgrade from ActiveMQ 5.4.2 to ActiveMQ 5.5.0 with non-empty KahaDB

Tags: activemq-classic

Good Day!

We have problem with issue AMQ-2736(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-2736) on remote sites and wants to upgrade to 5.5.0 version, wich resolved this problem.  But network connection with remote sites not stable and we will have non-empty KahaDB at some of them. Does 5.5.0 vesrion works with database created  by 5.4.2 version and we can simply upgrade software or we must empty all queues before upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this from first hand experience, but a colleague has successfully used ActiveMQ 5.5 against a KahaDB created from a previous version.  If you really want to try it out, just take a file system copy of the entire dataDirectory from version 5.4.2, and point your 5.5 installation to that copy within your activemq.xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I tried latest Fuse Message Broker  maintenance release for ActiveMQ 5.4.2 - apache-activemq-5.4.2-fuse-02-00  - and it works good - all "trash" files are removed and we have not detected any message lost or corruption